# How to drawn custom values on yAxis in MPAndroidChart Bar Chart?

Tags: android, android-studio, bar-chart

I want to show my own values on yAxis in Barchart, I wrote a code snippet (value formatter) but application crashes when I use it,

```
public class YAixsFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter
{
    List<String> time;

    public YAixsFormatter(List<String> time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {

        return time.get((int)value).concat(" mins");
    }
```

Comment: Please place your logcat issues.

Comment: @OmidNejadabbasi logcat is here.

 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 28, size is 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)

Comment: sorry !! Idon't know about `IAxisValueFormatter`.